# Check if curl response is empty

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have a simple shell script where I am doing a cURL and based on the response if empty or not wants to log a flag. I tried null check but it still goes to else part.

Script : test.sh

```
    RESP=`curl  -m 600 -X POST -H "Accept: application/json" ......`  #curl response
    #if [ -z "$RESP" ] && echo "Empty"
    if [ ${#RESP[@]} -eq 0 ];
    then
     echo "APIName=Test1Api,  TicketRaised=N"
    else
     echo "RESPONSE is NOT NULL"
     echo -e "APIName=Test1Api, HTTP_STATUS=$HTTP_STATUS, totalTime=$TIME_TAKEN, Response=$RESP, TicketRaised=Y"
    fi
```

Output > (even if Response ie "RESP" if empty it goes into else part)

```
RESPONSE is NOT NULL
APIName=Test1Api, HTTP_STATUS=[], totalTime=545, Response=[], TicketRaised=Y
```

Comment: Is `RESP` an array?

Comment: `RESP` above will be a string, not an array. So, it doesn't make sense in my eyes to use `${#RESP[@]}`. When you run `curl  -m 600 -X POST -H "Accept: application/json" ......`, what kind of string is returned when you expect an empty string? Does that so-called empty string contain a new line at the end, for example?

Comment: Can you provide the result of echo $RESP command. For me empty cURL response satisfies [ -z $RESP] condition.

Comment: Yes Curl response is a json. I want to know if there is response or not based on that want to log a flag, completly new to script, let me know if any changes needed

Comment: @PierreFrançois when there is no response it is like the above log : Response=[] & when not null then : Response=[{"id":458725974,"state":"Analyze","title":"Test NOTIFICATION - SPIKE IN USEAGE for userID: 58768953986"}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deduce from your answer that what you call an empty answer is the empty JASON string `[]`.

So try:

```
RESP=`curl  -m 600 -X POST -H "Accept: application/json" ......`  #curl response
if [ $RESP = "[]" ]
then
  echo "APIName=Test1Api,  TicketRaised=N"
else
  echo "RESPONSE is NOT NULL"
  echo -e "APIName=Test1Api, HTTP_STATUS=$HTTP_STATUS, totalTime=$TIME_TAKEN, Response=$RESP, TicketRaised=Y"
fi
```

Be sure that there is no newline char after `[]`. Otherwise, you will have to adapt the code.

Comment: yes this works but why was checking for array or string not working, like I found on web, if u could explain that too.

Comment: one more thing I get response but it also show error " line 21: [: too many arguments"

Comment: What is the content of line 21 of your script?